# git - get direct descendants of A that connect to B

Tags: git, ancestor

Is it possible to get the list of revisions that direct descendants of A that are direct ancestors of B? I I try `git log A..B` I will get the list of revisions that are ancestors of B that are not in the history of A, which is not exactly what I want. I need only revisions that directly connect A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: add `--ancestry-path` to your revision specification.  (This works for any command that uses commit-graph-walking, including `git log` and `git rev-list`.)  But I will note that I'm not sure what you mean by the adjective "direct" here.

Note that `A..B` means `B ^A`, i.e., use the set `ancestors(B) - ancestors(A)` (where subtraction here is set-subtraction).  Adding `--ancestry-path` means that after doing the set subtraction (or more accurately, while constructing the subtracted set), Git also subtracts away any commit that is not a descendant of the negated revision `A`.

Internally, Git does this by marking negated commit hash IDs (like `A` in `A..B` or `B ^A`) with a flag called BOTTOM.  Such commits are collected into a "bottom list" and Git makes sure that each commit *C* that might be in the `A..B` range has a bottom-commit as one of its ancestors.  This matters if you use `git rev-list --ancestry-path X ^Y ^Z` for instance: commits can be descendants  of `Y` *or* `Z`.\

---

Here's an example graph fragment showing which commits are selected (`●`) or not-selected (`○`) even though they are "in the range" of `A..B`:

```
...--A--●---●--B--...
   \  \    /
    ○--●--●
```

Note that commit `A` is not selected, and commit `B` is selected, here.

Comment: Haven't checked on it yet, but sounds like my answer so marking it as such. Thanks!